# Access VBA Nested IF Statements with Loops and Concatenated Text if conditions are met

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

We got a large data dump. I need to concatenate the [Long Text] field, so the users can manipulate the that field easier.  I know I am missing a row counter calculation, but I think I am making this more complicated than it should be and/or not enough.  Can someone please review this code and clean it up for me? I have searched for this and combined what I could into 1 code.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim strLongText As String

'Ensuring the order is correct
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from dbo_tblRouter Order By Plant, Material, GrC, UOpAc;")


'declare i for row counter
Dim i As Integer

    ' Set up IF condition to say IF Material(i) = Matertial(i+1) AND
    ' Plant(i) = Plant(i+1) AND OpAc(i) = OpAC(i+1) AND GrC(i) = GrC(i+1) THEN
    ' CONCATENATE(&) Long_Text
    ' DO this WHILE these Conditions continue to be met
    ' Then exit condition and run to the next row
    ' Stop at the EOF

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
    If dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i) = dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i) + 1 Then
        ElseIf dbo_tblRouter.Material(i) = dbo_tblRouter.Material(i) + 1 Then
            ElseIf dbo_tblRouter.GrC(i) = dbo_tblRouter.GrC(i) + 1 Then
                ElseIf dbo_tblRouter.UOpAC(i) = dbo_tblRouter.UOpAC(i) + 1 Then
                    While True
                        With rs
                            .FindFirst "RowNumber" = 0
                            strLongText = dbo_tblRouter.[Long Text]
                            rs.MoveNext
                        While Not rs.EOF
                            ' Add a soft return and concatenate with the next row
                            strLongText = strLongText & Chr(10) & dbo_tblRouter.[Long Text]
                            rs.MoveNext
                        Wend
                            ' Put the concatenated data into this empty memo field
                            .Edit
                            .Fields("LText") = strLongText
                            .Update
                        End With
                    Wend
            rs.MoveNext
    End If
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You really haven't explained what your exact goal is (current code might not be what you want), what problem you're facing, example data/output etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure what you're trying to do, but you have quite a bit wrong already.

```
dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i) = dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i) + 1
```

Will never be true. I think you mean:

```
dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i) = dbo_tblRouter.Plant(i + 1)
```

And doing a:

```
If [condition 1} Then
   ElseIf  [condition 2} Then
```

Is not a nested IF statement. The second line only executes if the first line is false. This is a nest IF:

```
If [condition 1} Then
   If  [condition 2} Then
```

This will never end. It's a forever loop because you're not testing a variable.

```
While True
Wend
```

Plus, although `While/Wend` works, it has been depreciated for over 20 years. `Do/Loop` is the replacement.

You're using `rs.MoveNext` in 2 different places. Not sure why. But changing the record pointer in the inner loop changes it in the outer loop as well.